# Can I have more than one operating system?

Tags: installation

I have a new laptop with windows xp. I want to install ubuntu but I want to have both operating systems: Ubuntu and windows xp. What can I do?

Comment: yes its possible , https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 2):

Many if not most people choose to do just that, installing Linux (Ubuntu) for daily usage and keeping their default Windows install for certain programs not supported on Linux (such as Netflix, iTunes, several games, etc.).

To install Ubuntu alongside Windows on a separate (aka a separate segment of your hard drive from your default C: drive), burn or purchase an Ubuntu live CD, pop it in your DVD drive and reboot. You can create one by downloading the proper .iso (64 or 32-bit) from [Ubuntu's website](http://www.ubuntu.com) and burning it onto a completely new, blank DVD.

Once you boot with the DVD in the tray, you should be prompted to install Ubuntu. Follow the directions and **make sure you select the option to install alongside Windows, not to replace/remove Windows**. If all goes well, after you install Ubuntu you'll be prompted with a screen after boot to select Windows XP or Ubuntu to load.

There's another, much easier option to simulate an Ubuntu dual-boot, however. Download the Windows installer for Ubuntu off of [Ubuntu's website](http://www.ubuntu.com) and run it. You'll create a virtual hard drive within your Windows partition and be able to run Ubuntu almost like you would a dual-boot. However, this will cost a slight performance decrease and you won't be able to hibernate (which is notable for laptops). It is easier to install and easier to remove, though, as you can uninstall it just like a program in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used ubuntu before?  If not, I highly recommend installing wubi here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows

This installs ubuntu within windows and allows you to pick windows or ubuntu on boot up.
It's not a traditional install but it is much easier.

Now if you are really hard set on installing it to it's own partition, I would recommend using the steps provided in this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LokDqte3sA4

Honestly the traditional install is not too difficult but if you're not comfortable with messing with partitions than I wouldn't recommend it just yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely have them both.
In the installation of Ubuntu you will be asked if you'd like to install Ubuntu alongside with Windows or if you'd like to totally replace windows. Just pick the alongside option and you're good. :)